# Android tracking the user installed from Facebook ,Twitter or Instagram in our android Application?

Tags: android, facebook

can I able to get whether my android application installed from Facebook
Advert, Twitter or Instagram.I want to save this data in my
application.

I have researched that it was unable to get Facebook and Twitter
referrals data in my app.At least I need to save from where my app
installed from Facebook, Twitter or Instagram.